# Existe uma maneira de saber em que arquivo uma parte do html está?

Tags: php, javascript

Estou trabalhando em um site que todas as funções foram divididas em diversas pastas e subpastas. (Suspeito que esse seja o mais comum)

Eu gostaria de saber se existe uma maneira eficaz de identificar em qual .php ou .html .js etc está o trecho de código que desejo mudar.

Exemplo:

A index.php faz as chamadas dos arquivos header.php footer.php e conteudo.php, mas esses arquivos fazem chamada a outros...

Qual ferramenta eu usaria para saber qual arquivo contem o código de um titulo x?

Atualmente utilizo o f12 (console de ferramentas) para ver o código completo, seleciono o trecho que desejo e fico dando crtl + f nos arquivos. Mas como o html que o navegador le já é processado muitas vezes não acho com facilidade.

Obrigado.

Comment: IDEs e editores de texto nao sao ferramentas de busca ideais.
Use o [agent ransack](https://www.mythicsoft.com/agentransack)

Comment: O sublime me ajuda bastante com o Find in folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O que poderia ser feito é utilizar alguma **IDE** para o desenvolvimento do site ou algum editor de texto que forneça suporte para `HTML` ou contenha *plugins* que facilitem sua vida.

ps: Um editor de texto leve e simples para utilizar é o `Sublime`. No site oficial pode ser encontrado para download.

Comment: Quais Plugins do sublime poderiam me ajudar ?

Comment: Dá uma olhada aqui: http://www.tekzoom.com.br/sublime-extensoes-plugins/

Aí fala bastante do Sublime. Eu te recomendei o Sublime por ele ser mais completo e te dar mais suporte caso queira desenvolver usando apenas ele ou realizar modificações no código...Mas, se quiser algo mais emergencial, instala o NotepadQQ, abre múltiplos arquivos e faz uma busca geral no arquivo.

Mas em grau de opinião, recomendo a instalação do Sublime.

Comment: Muito Obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Em editores de texto como o Notepad++ tem opção para buscar em mútiplos arquivos recursivamente em subpastas.

Esse pode ser o jeito mais fácil para casos como o descrito na pergunta.

<sub>*Considerando que nenhum desses dados estejam num banco de dados.</sub>

Comment: Muito Obrigado.